# Replace dashes with letters in hangman game in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to implement hangman in Elixir, and I am confused as to how I should replace a dash in my placeholder word with a correctly guessed letter (a the appropriate index). I have tried to use the `slice/3` and `replace/4` functions without much luck. Here is the function where I check if the letter entered by the user is in the secret word, and where I attempt to insert that letter into the placeholder containing dashes:

```
def check_match(word, guess) do 
    len = String.length(word)
    str = String.duplicate("_ ", len)
    if String.contains? word, guess do
        {index, length} = :binary.match(word, guess)
        #String.slice(str, index, len) <> guess <> String.slice(str, index+1, len)
        IO.puts String.replace(str, " ", guess) 
    else
         IO.puts str
    end
end
```

I call `check_match/2` inside `guess_word/2` (which also contains my game logic):

```
def guess_word(word, duration) do  
    gs = IO.gets("enter letter: ") 
    guess = String.trim(gs)
    put(duration, guess)
    update_letters()
    check_match(word, guess)
    if duration > 0 && !check_win(word, guess) do
        guess_word(word, duration - 1)
    end    
end
```

Perhaps I am trying to replace the dashes in the wrong part of the program. How would I go about replacing a dash at the correct index?

For example, the secret word is foo:

`_ _ _`

User guesses `f`

`f _ _`

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/JkSefm1S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search through the string to find the letter(s) one might use [`Regex.run/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#run/3) and/or [`Regex.scan/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3) with `return: :index` option. Since there might be many occurrences of the letter in the word, `scan` seems to be better candidate here:

```
iex> word = "barbaz"
iex> letter = "b" 
iex> Regex.scan ~r/#{letter}/, word, return: :index
[[{0, 1}], [{3, 1}]]
```

Those are tuples, representing `{index, length}`. Now we can modify the word to show to the user. Imagine, the user had already `"a"` opened, and she guesses `"r"` now:

```
iex> guessed = "_a__a_"
iex> letter = "r" 
iex> [[{idx, _}]] = Regex.scan ~r/#{letter}/, word, return: :index
[[{2, 1}]]

iex> String.slice(guessed, 0..idx-1) <> 
...>     letter <> 
...>     String.slice(guessed, idx+1..String.length(guessed))
"_ar_a_"
```

Of course, to handle multiple occurrences, the code required to be updated, but the main idea, I hope, is clear.